# Kubernetes log, User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get services in the namespace

Tags: kubernetes

`Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get services in the namespace "mycomp-services-process"`

For the above issue I have created "mycomp-service-process" namespace and checked the issue.

But it shows again message like this:

`Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. User "system:serviceaccount:mycomp-services-process:default" cannot get services in the namespace "mycomp-services-process"`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Creating a namespace won't, of course, solve the issue, as that is not the problem at all.

In the first error the issue is that `serviceaccount` default in default namespace `can not get services` because it does not have access to list/get services. So what you need to do is assign a role to that user using `clusterrolebinding`.

Following the set of minimum privileges, you can first create a role which has access to list services:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: service-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

What above snippet does is create a clusterrole which can list, get and watch services. (You will have to create a yaml file and apply above specs)

Now we can use this clusterrole to create a clusterrolebinding:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding service-reader-pod \
  --clusterrole=service-reader  \
  --serviceaccount=default:default
```

In above command the `service-reader-pod` is name of clusterrolebinding and it is assigning the service-reader clusterrole to default serviceaccount in default namespace. Similar steps can be followed for the second error you are facing.

In this case I created `clusterrole` and `clusterrolebinding` but you might want to create a `role` and `rolebinding` instead. You can check the [documentation in detail here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am able to proceed after applying above solutions.

Comment: I think the namespace should be removed from the ClusterRole. According to the docs ClusterRoles are not namespaced: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole

Comment: This solved for me : https://kubecloud.io/kubernetes-dashboard-on-arm-with-rbac-61309310a640

Answer (score 33):

**This is only for non prod clusters**

You should bind service account `system:serviceaccount:default:default` (which is the default account bound to Pod) with role `cluster-admin`, just create a yaml (named like `fabric8-rbac.yaml`) with following contents:

```
# NOTE: The service account `default:default` already exists in k8s cluster.
# You can create a new account following like this:
#---
#apiVersion: v1
#kind: ServiceAccount
#metadata:
#  name: <new-account-name>
#  namespace: <namespace>

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: fabric8-rbac
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    # Reference to upper's `metadata.name`
    name: default
    # Reference to upper's `metadata.namespace`
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Then, apply it by running `kubectl apply -f fabric8-rbac.yaml`.

If you want unbind them, just run `kubectl delete -f fabric8-rbac.yaml`.

Comment: While you're not going to get "access denied" error messages after doing this, I would **strongly** suggest not assigning the `cluster-admin` role to all pods in your Kubernetes cluster. If someone manages, for whatever reason, to find a security issue in one of your applications that gives them local command execution, you've just handed them an admin account for your entire cluster.

Comment: There is a deprecation warning on apiVersion `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1`, instead use `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` and warning would go away.

Comment: cluster-admin role must not be assigned to all pods in the kubernetes cluster. This generates high level vulnerability for your organization. This answer should not be flag as helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add.

This can also occur when you are redeploying an existing application to the wrong Kubernetes cluster that are similar.

Ensure you check to be sure that the Kubernetes cluster you're deploying to is the correct cluster.