# deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot create deployments.apps in the namespace

Tags: kubernetes

URL: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/diyclientapps/deployments

> )
>   "{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"deployments.apps
>   is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot
>   create deployments.apps in the namespace
>   \"diyclientapps\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"group":"apps","kind":"deployments"},"code":403}

I'm getting the above error when trying to create a deployment via the Kubernetes REST API.

Why? I don't understand the error message...

This occurs on a custom Kubernetes cluster... The above worked correctly on a local Minikube instance.

I can successfully create a deployment via: `kubectl run hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080`

Comment: Hi, Its RBAC error, you need to role bind your service account with cluster role or appropriate role.

Comment: Here is already [answerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973570/kubernetes-log-user-systemserviceaccountdefaultdefault-cannot-get-services)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes log, User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get services in the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973570/kubernetes-log-user-systemserviceaccountdefaultdefault-cannot-get-services)

Answer (score 32):

This is due to the RBAC functionality.

If you do not care about that at all (for example you're the only Kubernetes administrator):

**WARNING: This allows any Kubernetes user to have admin access.**

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --group=system:serviceaccounts
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/

Comment: Wow most upvoted! And this is the one the docs warn about because it grants escalated privilege across all namespaces :|

Comment: Wow why does that work??

Answer (score 10):

You could:

1. Create a Cluster role with the resource you need, in this case in the app resource group.
2. Bind it to your service account.

Example:

```
kubectl create clusterrole deployer --verb=get,list,watch,create,delete,patch,update --resource=deployments.apps

kubectl create clusterrolebinding deployer-srvacct-default-binding --clusterrole=deployer --serviceaccount=default:default
```

Answer (score 1):

It likely worked on minikube because it set up a permissive (insecure) policy for you.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#service-account-permissions for information about granting permissions to service accounts.

> Default RBAC policies grant scoped permissions to control-plane components, nodes, and controllers, but grant no permissions to service accounts outside the “kube-system” namespace (beyond discovery permissions given to all authenticated users).