# Deploying on kubernetes fails while using Gitlab runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to deploy my project on kubernetes using gitlab runner but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

but when I check the logs using `$ kubectl logs -f runner-gitlab` I get the following infos:

> WARNING: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1 
>   duration=51.567457707s job=296652672 project=14223129 runner=NzxLg7uo
>   ERROR: Failed to process runner                     builds=0
>   error=command terminated with exit code 1 executor=kubernetes
>   runner=NzxLg7uo

Anyone faced this before?

Comment: We need more information. Is that the full logs? Can you please post the text and not a screenshot? Can you post the entire `deploy.yml` file? What kind of application is running (provide some information about the application and what the end result should be / what kind of resources it might be using or depend on).

Comment: It looks like you are doing some custom `KUBECONFIG` management, which is different than the way GitLab expects that to work; however, the message is as clear as can be: the `gitlab-managed-apps:default` `ServiceAccount` does not have (likely **any**) the correct `RoleBinding` to be able to interact with `Deployments` in that namespace. You'll have to assign it the necessary `Role`, or use a `ServiceAccount` designed to deploy your app

Comment: Possible duplicate: [kubernetes - deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot create deployments.apps in the namespace - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173838/deployments-apps-is-forbidden-user-systemserviceaccountdefaultdefault-cann)

Comment: thank you for clearing the idea to me:
that issue was in fact a problem with gitlab-managed-apps, I managed to fix thins by following this [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/55933/designs)

Answer (score 0):

As @Firas Chbiki mentioned in the comments the issue has been solved by applying `ClusterRoleBinding` Kubernetes [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) assignment , granting the permissions, enclosed in **cluster-admin** `ClusterRole`, to the particular `gitlab-managed-apps:default` service account, as described [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/55933/designs).

This solution confirmed by the community members in [#56557](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/56557) and [#61116](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/61116) threads. Thanks @Andy Shinn, @Matthew L Daniel,  @Yasen for their efforts and collaboration.