# kubernetes dashboard (web ui) has nothing to display

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

After I deployed the webui (k8s dashboard), I logined to the dashboard but nothing found there, instead a list of errors in notification.

```
tatefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "statefulsets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "replicationcontrollers" in API group "" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
replicasets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "replicasets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
events is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
daemonsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "daemonsets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default" 2 minutes ago
error
namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:default" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Here is all my pods

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-58497c65d5-828dm     1/1     Running   0          64m   10.244.192.193   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-dblzp                            1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.140   cluster3-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-dwdvh                            1/1     Running   1          49m   157.245.57.139   cluster2-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-gskr2                            1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.133   cluster1-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-jm5rd                            1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.144   cluster4-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-m8htd                            1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.141   cluster3-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-n7d44                            1/1     Running   0          64m   157.245.57.146   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-wblpr                            1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.135   cluster2-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-wbrzf                            1/1     Running   1          29m   157.245.57.136   cluster1-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-wqwkj                            1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.142   cluster4-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-78fcd69978-cnzxv                     1/1     Running   0          64m   10.244.192.194   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-78fcd69978-f4ln8                     1/1     Running   0          64m   10.244.192.195   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-master-node1                            1/1     Running   1          64m   157.245.57.146   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-master-node1                  1/1     Running   1          64m   157.245.57.146   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-master-node1         1/1     Running   1          64m   157.245.57.146   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-2b5bz                             1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.144   cluster4-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-cslwc                             1/1     Running   3          49m   157.245.57.139   cluster2-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-hlvxc                             1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.140   cluster3-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-kkdqn                             1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.142   cluster4-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-sm7nq                             1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.133   cluster1-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-wm42s                             1/1     Running   0          64m   157.245.57.146   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-wslxd                             1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.141   cluster3-node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-xnh24                             1/1     Running   0          17m   157.245.57.135   cluster2-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-zvsqf                             1/1     Running   1          29m   157.245.57.136   cluster1-node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-master-node1                  1/1     Running   1          64m   157.245.57.146   master-node1     <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554-c4thn   1/1     Running   0          14m   10.244.14.65     cluster2-node2   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6-hwvj5        1/1     Running   0          14m   10.244.213.65    cluster1-node1   <none>           <none>
```

Here is all my nodes:

```
NAME             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
cluster1-node1   Ready    <none>                 29m   v1.22.1
cluster1-node2   Ready    <none>                 17m   v1.22.1
cluster2-node1   Ready    <none>                 17m   v1.22.1
cluster2-node2   Ready    <none>                 49m   v1.22.1
cluster3-node1   Ready    <none>                 17m   v1.22.1
cluster3-node2   Ready    <none>                 17m   v1.22.1
cluster4-node1   Ready    <none>                 17m   v1.22.1
cluster4-node2   Ready    <none>                 17m   v1.22.1
master-node1     Ready    control-plane,master   65m   v1.22.1
```

I suspect there is misconfiguration in kubernetes-dashboard namespace, so it cannot access the system.

Comment: Could you describe how did you set up your dashboard? Could you attach your yaml files?

Comment: This is how I setup my dashboard, using the k8s official doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/ with `https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/`

Comment: [This fix](https://github.com/andrewlock/blog-comments/discussions/92#discussioncomment-4703219) worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have recreated the situation according to the attached tutorial and it works for me.
Make sure, that you are [trying properly login](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui):

> To protect your cluster data, Dashboard deploys with a minimal RBAC configuration by default. Currently, Dashboard only supports logging in with a Bearer Token. To create a token for this demo, you can follow our guide on  [creating a sample user](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md).
>
> **Warning:**  The sample user created in the tutorial will have administrative privileges and is for educational purposes only.

You can also create `admin role`:

```yaml
kubectl create clusterrolebinding serviceaccounts-cluster-admin \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --group=system:serviceaccounts
```

**However, you need to know that this is potentially a very dangerous solution as you are granting root permissions to create pods for every user who has read secrets. You should use this method only for learning and demonstrating purpose.**

You can read more about this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174177/15407542) and more about [RBAC authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973570/kubernetes-log-user-systemserviceaccountdefaultdefault-cannot-get-services).

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied the proper ClusterRoleBinding for your kubernetes-dashboard and still have the *forbidden* message, please take a look at the **token** you are using for accessing the dashboard.

In `kubectl get serviceaccount kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml` look for .secrets.name. That's the token you need to use to login

Then `kubectl get secret <the token name> -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d`. Copy all the token. Notice you **should not** copy the last **%** character.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing the clusterRoles. You may follow [this link](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/4179#issuecomment-610078007) for READ_ONLY access to Dashboard.You might need to adopt some settings.