# kubernetes pods/nodes is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I'm using kubernetes on-prem

While I build gitlab using kubernetes has some problem.
I think it's related with serviceaccount or role-binding.
but couldn't find correct way

I found these posts

[Kubernetes log, User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get services in the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973570/kubernetes-log-user-systemserviceaccountdefaultdefault-cannot-get-services)

https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/3551

## my error logs

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/prometheus/current <==
2018-12-24_03:06:08.88786 level=error ts=2018-12-24T03:06:08.887812767Z caller=main.go:240 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:372: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"nodes\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
2018-12-24_03:06:08.89075 level=error ts=2018-12-24T03:06:08.890719525Z caller=main.go:240 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:320: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope"
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The issue is due to your default service account doesn't have the permission to get the nodes or pods at the cluster scope. The minimum cluster role and cluster role binding to resolve that is:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prom-admin
rules:
# Just an example, feel free to change it
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "nodes"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prom-rbac
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prom-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The above cluster role provide permission to default service account to access any pods or nodes in any namespace.

You can change the cluster role to provide more permission to service account, if you want to grant access all permission to default service account then, replace `resources: ["*"]` in `prom-admin`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Siner if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Comment: I forgot about this. Your answer will spread out to kubernetes users

Comment: Just to add, sometimes it can be **Role** and **RoleBinding** also.

Comment: This answer worked for me but I did have to add `namespace: default` to the subjects section at the bottom.

Comment: This solved for me: https://kubecloud.io/kubernetes-dashboard-on-arm-with-rbac-61309310a640

Comment: For folks landing here, the official documentation on this subject is located here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: The differentiator for me was the `kind: ClusterRole`. I was following docs that used `kubectl create role`, I needed `kubectl create clusterrole` to run node-related commands