# User cannot list resource at the cluster scope - Kubernetes HTTP Endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, rancher-desktop

```
kubernetes v1.23.6
rancher-desktop v1.3.0
```

I'm attempting to utlize the Kubernetes API HTTP endpoints from inside a pod. I have a Service Account Set up which should have the permissions to hit the API and return data, but I'm unable to get any useful results.

I'm getting a 403 Forbidden on elements I believe should be accessible to the ServiceAccount.

```
curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN" https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/default/pods/ubuntu
```

Where $KUBE_TOKEN is the value read from `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`

Returns:

```
https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/default/pods/ubuntu
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "default \"pods\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:podkiller\" cannot get resource \"default/ubuntu\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "pods",
    "kind": "default"
  },
  "code": 403
```

I originally had `Role` instead of `ClusterRole` and that allowed me to use the API, before that any request made would return forbidden.

I looked at some other posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605085/pods-is-forbidden-user-systemserviceaccountkubernetes-dashboardadmin-user) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908848/kubernetes-pods-nodes-is-forbidden) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151953/forbidden-resource-in-api-group-at-the-cluster-scope), but all seemed to be issues with either namespaces or not binding roles and accounts, which I think I have done correctly.

**ServiceAccount**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: podkiller
automountServiceAccountToken: true
```

**ClusterRole**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: podkiller
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods","nodes"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "delete"]
```

**ClusterRoleBinding**

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 name: podkiller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: podkiller
  namespace: default
roleRef:
 kind: ClusterRole
 name: podkiller
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

**Pod**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
spec:
  serviceAccountName: podkiller
  automountServiceAccountToken: true
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu
    command:
      - "sleep"
      - "604800"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: ubuntu
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score 0):

May I ask that which namespace does your Service Account podkiller reside? I suspect it's not in the namespace `default` as your ClusterRoleBinding indicates. Change it to the correct namespace might resolve your issue.

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 name: podkiller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: podkiller
  namespace: default => correct namespace
roleRef:
 kind: ClusterRole
 name: podkiller
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```